# sqlite: How can results be made unique according to a column

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

Currently, the following sqlite query returns 45 records. I know that only 4 albums exist. How can the query be made to return only those records that are unique to albumTable.album.

Pseudo Code: where albumTable.album is UNIQUE

```
    query = new StringBuilder();
    query.append("select albumTable.album, artistTable.artist, songTable.filepath ");
    query.append("from albumTable ");
    query.append("inner join artistTable ");
    query.append("on albumTable.artistID = artistTable.artistID ");
    query.append("inner join songTable ");
    query.append("on albumTable.albumID = songTable.albumID ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DISTINCT  for the selection.

For more info:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_distinct_keyword.htm

EDIT: Maybe you can select with distinct from the current result. Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT albumTable.album  
FROM (SELECT albumTable.album,
    artistTable.artist, songTable.filepath  from albumTable 
    inner join artistTable on albumTable.artistID = artistTable.artistID 
    inner join songTable on albumTable.albumID = songTable.albumID )
```

I don't have such database to test the query ...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your suggestion. However, I initially got an sql exception of albumTable.album doesn't exist. I fixed that problem by just using album but the result was only album data. I then added "select album, artist, filepath from (...)" but that returned 45 records when I should be getting 4.

Comment: I figured out the problem and I marked your answer as correct because your solution would have worked with some small modifications if not for the faulty logic I used. The problem is that a filepath is associated with a song not an album. Therefore, the result couldn't possibly be 4. I still need a filepath but only from a single song in that album. I'll make that task a sperate query.